# HttpSessionState Session bug on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session, session-cookies

I am currently working on a web project which uses the HttpSessionState Session object.
when a user is logged in, the Session object is filled with the user name, user id and some other properties.
this is what happens in the log-in page :

```
UserSession userSession = applicationManager.GetUserSession(userName);
Session["userSession"] = userSession;
```

and then in every page load on the code behind the first thing i'm doing is checking the session state like so :

```
UserSession session = (UserSession)Session["userSession"];

if (session == null /*|| !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated */ || session.UserId == 0 )
       AuthorizationServer.DeportUser();
```

when i close a tab in an internet explorer browser and then log in in another tab in the same browser it's works alright until in a certain page the Session object gets cleaned out from it's properties and the user gets kicked out of the web application (again, only in this certain page).
this problem does not happen in any other browser but internet explorer.

i do not see any particular problem in the developer tools and i am craving for a hint or direction for this bug.